# What type of architecture/design pattern does MERN follow?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, client-server, mern

I am a part of a project that is using the MERN stack and need info on how to structure my system architecture diagram. I am unsure whether MERN is a MVC, layered, client-server, or other architecture pattern.

I currently have a diagram on our github [wiki page](https://github.com/Intro-to-SE-Spring-2020/Chirpr/wiki/System-Architecture-Design), but my client said that this is not detailed enough. Can someone please chime in and help out.

I want to say MVC, but since React is the view, and all logic is within the Express controllers/models I am unsure whether this is truly a MVC pattern.

Comment: To use React Js in the frontend along with backend (Node, Express, and MongoDB) then, it is known as MVC architecture as mongoose model definition as Model, controller defining as Controller and View (ReactJs is added here). The combination of programming stacks such as MongoDB, Express, ReactJS, and NodeJs is known as the MERN stack design pattern.